# For an open set $A$ and connected closed set $B$, if $A \cap B$ is closed and nonempty, then, $B \subseteq A$

Tags: general-topology

I tried to show that

> For an open set $A$ and connected closed set $B$, if $C = A \cap B$ is closed and nonempty, then, $B \subseteq A$.

Proof:
Suppose for a contraction that $B \nsubseteq A$, or $B \setminus A \neq \varnothing$. From the definition of $C$,
$$
C \cap (B \setminus A) = \varnothing\\
C \cup (B \setminus A) = B
$$
Since $C$ and $B \setminus A$ are both closed, $\overline{C} \cap \overline{B \setminus A} = \varnothing$; hence, $C$ and $B \setminus A$ are separated, which contradicts to the assumption that $B$ is connected.

Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct, adding $\overline{C}\cap \overline{B-A}=\varphi$ is unnecessarily. A space is connected if it cannot be written as union of two disjoint open sets.

Comment: @IrbidMath But they are closed. Am I missing something? Thank you for the comment :)

Comment: You are not missing something I just think adding that the intersection of the closure is the empty set is not necessary if you want to show that a set $Y$ is disconnect it is enough if you can write it as a union of two disjoin (open/closed) subset in the relative top of $Y$.